# unable to implement vuelidate with renderless component - vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuelidate

I want to create a renderless form with vuejs - I'm using vuelidate for form validation. The form uses scoped slot to manage the model and controls.

Unfortunately i'm not able to implement the vuelidate for the form validation by renderless approach. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
Below is what i have tried.

**App.vue**

```
<renderless-form>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit" slot-scope="{ ele, submit }">
     <input type="email" v-model="ele.model.name" />
     <button> Submit </button>
  </form>
</renderless-form>

<script>
import renderlessFrom from "./components/renderless-form.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    "renderless-form": renderlessFrom
  }
};
</script>
```

**renderless-form.vue**

```
import { required, minLength, between } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        model: {
          name: ''
        }
      };
    },
    validation: model, //i am sceptical here how to put validation
    methods: {
      async submit() {
        console.log(this.model) 
      },
    },
    render() {
      return this.$scopedSlots.default({
        // Data
        ele: this.model,
        
        // Methods
        submit: this.submit,
      });
    },
  };
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article could answer your problem
https://medium.com/@crishellco/vuelidate-displaying-errors-simplified-156147b123d6

It suggests that you wrap your input in a FormGroup component, which exposes the scoped slot values "invalid" and "errors".

Demo :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-w86yq?file=/src/components/Form.vue

Answer (score 0):

The `renderlessForm` is missing the `validation` definition and the `el.model` reference does not exist.

See working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrc29ns0/1/)

Parent markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <renderless-form>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit" slot-scope="{ model, submit, validations }">
      <input type="email" v-model="model.name" />
      <button> Submit </button>

      <pre>{{ validations.model }}</pre>
    </form>
  </renderless-form>
</div>
```

Renderless form component:

```
Vue.component('renderless-form', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({
      model: this.model,
      submit: this.submit,
      validations: this.$v
    });
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      model: {
        name: ''
      }
    };
  },
  validations: {
    model: {
      name: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(5)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
        console.log("submit", this.model);
    }
  }
});
```